# Can't get avi files play using windows media player plugin

Tags: windows, media-player, media, avi

I'm using the following code to embed windows media player plugin into the page.

```
<object width="300" height="400" class="wmplayer" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" id="6234779631653533">
<param value="8444393059051444" name="id">  
<param value="http://localhost/mysite/media/water.avi" name="url">
<!-- [if !IE]  -->
<object width="300" height="400" type="application/x-ms-wmp" class="wmp" alt="" data="http://localhost/mysite/media/water.avi"></object>
<!-- [endif]  -->
```

The site at http://localhost/mysite/ is hosted by a Tomcat server(6.0). My problem is that for some avi files, wmp plugin can play nicely. For other avi files, wmp plugin only plays in 1 second.(file length is about ~20 seconds)

I got the same result in almost browsers (IE8, Firefox 5 and Chrome 12). If I don't put avi files in the tomcat server (the html page containing the code above and avi file now are in the same folder), wmp plugin plays smoothly for all avi files.(And off course, I can get all avi files play in standalone windows media player).

My question is that for some avi files, why wmp plugin only plays in ~ 1 second ?

Thank you very much.